# Sheet.Range(Sheet,Cells(x,y), Sheet.Cells(x2,y2)) Syntax

Tags: excel, vba, syntax

I would like to add multiple Cells through the .Cells(x,y) Syntax to a Range named "ValueRange" like so:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim j As long
Dim Valuerange As Range

j = 6 'rowNumber 6
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("My Worksheet1")
Set Valuerange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(j, 3), ws.Cells(j, 5), ws.Cells(j, 7), ws.Cells(j, 9))
```

and I would like to Select this range through the same format later after changing j (rowNumber)

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(j, 3), ws.Cells(j, 5), ws.Cells(j, 7), ws.Cells(j, 9)).Select
```

But I always get errors with this Syntax "Wrong Number of Arguments or invalid property assignment"

Can anyone help?
Cheers

Comment: The `Range` object takes two arguments: upper right and lower left corners of the range.  If you want to refer to non-contiguous ranges, you will need to `Union` the several contiguous range objects. Also, why are you using `Select`? It is rarely necessary, and frequently leads to problems. See [How to avoid Using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) (*it is an easily understood mistake as the macro recorder usually includes multiple selects and activates*)

Comment: `Set Valuerange = Union(ws.Cells(j, 3), ws.Cells(j, 5), ws.Cells(j, 7), ws.Cells(j, 9))`

Comment: Two expressions on why you thought it may work (but it doesn't): `Set Valuerange = ws.Range("C6,E6,G6,I6")` hence `Set Valuerange = ws.Range("" & ws.Cells(j, 3).Address & "," & ws.Cells(j, 5).Address & "," & ws.Cells(j, 7).Address & "," & ws.Cells(j, 9).Address & "")`. The parameter has to be a string. Test each of them with `Debug.Print Valuerange.Address`.

Comment: Thanks you guys! Ron explained it perfectly and I got it to work with the Union Statement from Thomas. Can I Check an answer even though its a comment? Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

See comments of question for easy answer through using a Union-Statement instead of Range-Object